# ESLint in Eclipse display errors as warn or info

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eslint

I am using ESLint in Eclipse and the hints provided by ESLint are displayed as Errors (But they are only code improvement hints and not errors).

Is there a way i can configure ESLint / Eclipse to display those Errors as Warning or Info instead as Errors?

Answer (score 1):

ESLint automatically looks for `.eslintrc.json` files. You can run `eslint --init` to have ESLint create a configuration file for you, or you can create one manually. Here's an example modified from the [Getting Started guide](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration):

```
{
    "rules": {
        "eqeqeq": "off",
        "quotes": ["warn", "double"],
        "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
}
```

In this example, the `eqeqeq` rule will be disabled, `quotes` will show warnings, and `semi` will give you errors.

Comment: yes i have a config file for ESLint, but i want to know, if i can redirect the errors into warnings. But anways +1 for the link.